# Exclude content meta-data getting added to file upload using Webclient springboot

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, webclient

I am trying to upload a file to ftp server using WebClient in spring boot.

Below is my code:

```
URI uri = new URI(domain +folderName+ fileName);
MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
builder.part("file", resource);
ResponseEntity<Object> response = webClient.put().uri(uri).contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, auth)                     
 .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build())).retrieve().toEntity(Object.class).block();
```

However, when the file gets uploaded, I can see content meta-data being included at the top of the file as seen below:

[image]

How do I avoid this content meta-data getting added in my file?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `fromMultipartData(builder.build())`  with `fromResource(new FileSystemResource(resource))`

and you can completely remove

```
MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
builder.part("file", resource);
```

I know i am late here, but this answer may assist someone